# jQuery - calculate the scroll ratio of an element when it enters the veiwport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, viewport

How can I calculate the scroll ratio of an element as soon as it enters the viewpoint?

My combination of code from a couple of sources:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var initY = $('.scrollratio').offset().top
  var height = $('.scrollratio').height()
  var endY  = initY + $('.scrollratio').height()

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop()

    var visible = isVisible(document.getElementById("demo"))
    console.log(visible)

    if (visible) {
      console.log('in view')
    } else {
      console.log('out of view')
    }

    if(visible){
      var diff = scroll - initY
      var ratio = Math.round((diff / height) * 100)
      $('#note').text(ratio)
    }
  })
})

// Check if the element is in the viewport.
// http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/check-if-element-is-visible/
function isVisible(node) {
    // Am I visible?
    // Height and Width are not explicitly necessary in visibility detection, the bottom, right, top and left are the
    // essential checks. If an image is 0x0, it is technically not visible, so it should not be marked as such.
    // That is why either width or height have to be > 0.
    var rect = node.getBoundingClientRect()
    return (
        (rect.height > 0 || rect.width > 0) &&
        rect.bottom >= 0 &&
        rect.right >= 0 &&
        rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.left <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    )
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #777;
}

body {
  background:#171717;
}

.section-1 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.scrollratio {
  height: 2000px;
  background:red;
}

#note {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="note" ></div>
<div class="section-1"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="scrollratio" id="demo"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

It gets **negative values** when the element (the red box) enters the viewport, and **only** gets the positive values when the element's top starts passing the window's top.

Any ideas how to get the **positive values** as soon as the element is in the viewport?

**EDIT:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var initY = $('.scrollratio').offset().top
  var height = $('.scrollratio').height()
  var endY  = initY + $('.scrollratio').height()
  var wHeight = $(window).height();

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop()

    var visible = isVisible(document.getElementById("demo"))

    if(visible){
      var diff = scroll + wHeight - initY
      var ratio = Math.round((diff / height) * 100)
      $('#note').text(ratio)
    }
  })
})

// Check if the element is in the viewport.
// http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/check-if-element-is-visible/
function isVisible(node) {
    // Am I visible?
    // Height and Width are not explicitly necessary in visibility detection, the bottom, right, top and left are the
    // essential checks. If an image is 0x0, it is technically not visible, so it should not be marked as such.
    // That is why either width or height have to be > 0.
    var rect = node.getBoundingClientRect()
    return (
        (rect.height > 0 || rect.width > 0) &&
        rect.bottom >= 0 &&
        rect.right >= 0 &&
        rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.left <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    )
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #777;
}

body {
  background:#171717;
}

.section-1 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.scrollratio {
  height: 2000px;
  background:red;
}

#note {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="note" ></div>
<div class="scrollratio" id="demo"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's simply because you haven't accounted for the height of the window as well. Just add `var wHeight = $(window).height();` to your calculations and I believe it's solved. See below. Also note that I've added the `wheight` variable outside the scroll event as it's unnecessary to call it each time - however, you might want to account for window resizes and update the variable in such case. 
PS: I've added the `wHeight` variable in the calculation of `var diff =`

**EDIT:** as requested I've updated the javascript below, setting the `wHeight` conditionally based on whether it's within the "first" window height or not.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

  var initY = $('.scrollratio').offset().top
  var height = $('.scrollratio').height()
  var endY  = initY + $('.scrollratio').height();

  if(initY > $(window).height()){
  wHeight = $(window).height();
  } else {
  wHeight = 0;
  };

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop()
    var visible = isVisible(document.getElementById("demo"));

    if(visible){
      var diff = scroll + wHeight - initY
      var ratio = Math.round((diff / height) * 100);
      $('#note').text(ratio)
    }
  })
})

// Check if the element is in the viewport.
// http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/check-if-element-is-visible/
function isVisible(node) {
    // Am I visible?
    // Height and Width are not explicitly necessary in visibility detection, the bottom, right, top and left are the
    // essential checks. If an image is 0x0, it is technically not visible, so it should not be marked as such.
    // That is why either width or height have to be > 0.
    var rect = node.getBoundingClientRect()
    return (
        (rect.height > 0 || rect.width > 0) &&
        rect.bottom >= 0 &&
        rect.right >= 0 &&
        rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.left <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    )
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #777;
}

body {
  background:#171717;
}

.section-1 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.scrollratio {
  height: 2000px;
  background:red;
}

#note {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="note" ></div>
<div class="section-1"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="scrollratio" id="demo"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

In case you would like to make the script "resize-proof" as well as avoid the negative numbers in case the `initY < $(window).height()`, you can do as follows (relies on global variables):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function setVars(){
  initY = $('.scrollratio').offset().top
  height = $('.scrollratio').height()
  endY  = initY + $('.scrollratio').height();

  if(initY > $(window).height()){
  wHeight = $(window).height();
  } else {
  wHeight = 0;
  };
};
setVars();
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop()
    var visible = isVisible(document.getElementById("demo"));

    if(visible){
      var diff = scroll + wHeight - initY;
      var ratio = Math.round((diff / height) * 100);
      if(ratio >= 0){
        $('#note').text(ratio);
      };
    }
  })
 $(window).on("resize", setVars);
})

// Check if the element is in the viewport.
// http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/check-if-element-is-visible/
function isVisible(node) {
    // Am I visible?
    // Height and Width are not explicitly necessary in visibility detection, the bottom, right, top and left are the
    // essential checks. If an image is 0x0, it is technically not visible, so it should not be marked as such.
    // That is why either width or height have to be > 0.
    var rect = node.getBoundingClientRect()
    return (
        (rect.height > 0 || rect.width > 0) &&
        rect.bottom >= 0 &&
        rect.right >= 0 &&
        rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.left <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: It has a minor bug I guess - when the red box is at the top (without `section-1`), the value it gets is started at 10 or 40 above, not at 0. see my edit above.

Comment: Well it will depend on your goal for this ratio. Including the window height shows that the ratio should be 0 when the div enters the screen from the bottom (when you scroll to it). When the `section-1` is removed, the div is already at the top of the screen, hence the ratio is > 0.  However one way to "accomodate" both needs is to make the `wHeight` conditional - see the updated answer in a second

Comment: @laukok updated answer - took a little more than a second :)

Comment: Also added a further update to account for resizes and the possibility for negative number